Why these constants in angular spectrum in optics?
I'm following the book 'Scattering and Diffraction in Physical Optics Second Edition' by Manuel Nieto-Vesperinas.
In chapter 2 the angular spectrum is derived. We consider some scatters located in the half-space $z\leq 0$. We can then express the scalar wavefunction in $z>0$ using only the field at $z=0$:
$$
U(x,y,z)=\iint^{\infty}_{-\infty} a(p,q) \exp [ik(px+qy+mz)]\mathrm\, dp\,\mathrm dq\tag{2.12}
$$
where
$$
a(p,q)=\left(\frac{k}{2\pi}\right)^2\iint^{\infty}_{-\infty}U(x,y, 0)\exp [-ik(px+qy)]\mathrm\, dp\,\mathrm dq\tag{2.16}
$$
and
$$
\begin{cases}
m=\sqrt{1-p^2-q^2} & p^2+q^2\leq 1\tag{2.9}\\
m=i\sqrt{p^2+q^2-1} & p^2+q^2> 1
\end{cases}
$$
So far so good and I could follow the derivation of these expressions. In section 2.6 this integral is rewritten in an angular form.
$$
U(\mathbf r)=\frac{ik}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm d\beta\int_{\mathscr D^+}\mathrm d\alpha\,\sin(\alpha )F(\alpha,\beta)\exp(ik\,\mathbf s\cdot \mathbf r)\quad \text{for $z>0$}\tag{2.23}
$$
where $$\frac{ik}{2\pi}F(\alpha,\beta)=\cos(\alpha) a(p,q)\tag{2.24}$$
and $\mathscr D^+$ is an oddly shaped contour in the complex plane.
My questions are regarding this last expression.

Why is the factor $k$ in there? It seems completely arbitrary. What are the units of $a$ and $U$ and $F$?
What does the factor $i$ do there? It seems again completely arbitrary

I do understand that the factor $1/2\pi$ and $\sin\alpha$ are to make the expression look like a nice angular integral.

How is $\mathbf{s}$ defined in the book ? Is there really a $e^{-ikmz}$ term in equation (2.16) ?

@MauvaiseFoi The $ikmz$ term in 2.16 was indeed a typo. $\mathbf s$ is defined as $\mathbf s=(p,q, m)$.

The scalar wavefunction $U(\mathbf{r})$ represents a physical field like electric field or pressure, with units we'll denote as $[U]$. From the Cartesian form of the angular spectrum representation:
$$
U(x,y,z)=\iint^{\infty}_{-\infty} a(p,q) \exp [ik(px+qy+mz)]\mathrm\, dp\,\mathrm dq
$$
Since the exponential term is dimensionless and $dp$, $dq$ are dimensionless direction cosines, $a(p,q)$ must have the same units as $U(\mathbf{r})$, namely $[U]$. We can verify this from the definition of $a(p,q)$:
$$
a(p,q)=\left(\frac{k}{2\pi}\right)^2\iint^{\infty}_{-\infty}U(x,y, 0)\exp [-ik(px+qy)]\mathrm\, dx\,\mathrm dy
$$
Here, $k$ has units $L^{-1}$, so $(k/2\pi)^2$ has units $L^{-2}$. The integral over $dx\,dy$ has units $L^2$, the exponential is dimensionless, and $U(x,y,0)$ has units $[U]$. These combine to give $a(p,q)$ units of $[U]$.
In the angular representation:
$$
U(\mathbf r)=\frac{ik}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm d\beta\int_{\mathscr D^+}\mathrm d\alpha\,\sin(\alpha )F(\alpha,\beta)\exp(ik\,\mathbf s\cdot \mathbf r)
$$
Looking at this equation, we see that since $k$ has units $L^{-1}$ and all angular terms and the exponential are dimensionless, for $F(\alpha,\beta)$ to give $U(\mathbf{r})$ units of $[U]$, it must have units of $[U]L$. This is confirmed by the relationship:
$$
\frac{ik}{2\pi}F(\alpha,\beta)=\cos(\alpha) a(p,q)
$$
From this we can solve for $F(\alpha,\beta)$:
$$
F(\alpha,\beta) = \frac{2\pi\cos(\alpha)}{ik}a(p,q)
$$
Since $1/k$ has units $L$ and $a(p,q)$ has units $[U]$, this confirms that $F(\alpha,\beta)$ has units $[U]L$.
The factor $k$ appears from the coordinate transformation between $(p,q)$ and $(\alpha,\beta)$. The Jacobian of this transformation is $\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)$, giving:
$$
dp\,dq = \cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)\,d\alpha\,d\beta
$$
The factor $i$ serves a different purpose - it ensures correct phase relationships between propagating and evanescent waves, and arises naturally from the stationary phase method used in deriving the angular spectrum representation. This phase factor is crucial for properly describing how waves propagate through space.
So in summary: $U(\mathbf{r})$ and $a(p,q)$ have units $[U]$, while $F(\alpha,\beta)$ has units $[U]L$. The factor $k$ comes from coordinate transformation mathematics, while $i$ handles phase relationships in wave propagation. These factors are not arbitrary but emerge naturally from the underlying physics and mathematics of wave propagation.

Thank you so much! I still don't understand the factor $k$ though. The factor $sin\alpha$ is still in the integral and the factor $\cos\alpha$ is absorbed in the definition of $F$, so there is no factor left to equal $k$. Besides, I don't see how either cos or sin would be equal to $k$.

For the factor $i$ I will have to look up a nice derivation of the stationary phase method. Thanks for pointing that out.
